# Are arrays different after concatenation?

Tags: c++

I need to use char arrays to check if the letters in the first two arrays are in the third one.
I can't use strings, cstrings or vectors. Only standard char[].

```
    char a[150];
    cin >> a;
    char b[150];
    cin >> b;
    char c[150];
    cin >> c;
    char ab[150];
    strcpy (ab, a);
    strcat (ab, b);
    cout << std::is_permutation(begin(ab), end(ab), begin(c));
```

Expected output:

```
aed bcf fbcade >> 1
test oen notest >> 0
```

I tried sorting the arrays first or using equals but after concatenation the strings seem to be different.

Comment: Since this is C++ it'd be a lot better to use `std::string` if that's an option. Is this an assignment constraint? These courses are infuriating in that they miss the entire point of C++. Hope you're not faring too badly.

Comment: You may need to specify the beginning and end of the text in the string, not the beginning and end of the buffer. This requires `strlen()`.

Comment: It is an assignment... and the arrays need to take up to 150 letters.I will look into strlen(), thank you!

Comment: What happens if `a` is 150 characters and `b` is 150 characters?

Comment: In my case I throw an error

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that `std::end(ab)` doesn't return end of string, but end of array.

So `std::end(ab)` is `ab + 150` for any content.

You want `strlen`:

```
cout << std::is_permutation(begin(ab), begin(ab) + strlen(ab), begin(c));
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/k29rHb)